# return object's properties from related data in symfony json result

Tags: php, json, symfony

I am attempting to return a list of comments related to a an entity. The query results on when it runs and returns, the related field does not provide a meaningful result.

Here is the comment entity declarations

```
/**
     * @var Books
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Books")
     */
    private $imagefk;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Users")
     */
    private $userfk;
```

This is my controller snippets of codes that fetches all the comment a user commented to a particular book

```
private function serializeComments(Comments $cmt) {
        return array(
            'message' => $cmt->getMessage(),
            'userid' => $cmt->getUserfk(),
            'bookid' => $cmt->getBookfk(),
        );
    }
```

the below function calls the function above

```
public function getAllCommentsAction($books)
    {


    $messages = $em->getRepository("AppBundle")->findBy(
        array(
            "imagefk" => $books
        )
    );


    $data = array();

    foreach ($messages as $message)
    {
        array_push($data, $this->serializeComments($message));
    }
    $response = new Response(json_encode($data), 200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
    }
```

Here is the result of attempt

```
[{"message":"This is comment for a user one","userid":{"__initializer__":{},"__cloner__":{},"__isInitialized__":false},"bookid":{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/xxx\/web\/uploads\/pdf\/5ub3uy8zv09cee2avi11.pdf"}}
```

Please how can I return the objects properties from this result instead of this

```
"userid":{"__initializer__":{},"__cloner__":{},"__isInitialized__":false},"bookid":{"path":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2:88\/xxx\/web\/uploads\/pdf\/5ub3uy8zv09cee2avi11.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing the object properties:

```
'userid' => $cmt->getUserfk()->getId(),
```

instead of

```
'userid' => $cmt->getUserfk(),
```

Hope this help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870881/get-a-list-of-all-the-object-properties-of-different-users-that-a-user-is-follow