# get a list of all the object properties of different users that a user is following - symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am building a books application where by for a user to see the books you upload he/she must follow you or become your friend.
The application is made up 3 entities Books, Users and Follow.
Here is a sample structure Follow table

```
id | followered_id | followed_id
1  | 1             | 2
2  | 1             | 3
3  | 2             | 1
```

From the above illutration user 1 is following/friend to 2 and 3. So all their books should appear on his profile. In the controller below I am able to come up with an attempt but I have to click on each user to view the books he has uploaded

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $me = $this->getAuthedUser(1);

        $follows = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Follow")->findBy(["follower" => $me]);
        $followeds = [];
        foreach ($follows as $follow) {
            $followeds[] = $follow->getFollowed();
        }

        $followables = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->findAll();



        return $this->render("@App/index.html.twig", [
            "me" => $me,
            "followeds" => $followeds, //this
            "followables" => $followables,
        ]);
```

below is the view of the above controller method

```
<h1>Welcome, {{ me.username }}!</h1>

        <h2>Your followed people:</h2>
        {% if followeds is not empty %}
            <ul>
            {% for followed in followeds %}
                <li>{{ followed.username }} (<a href="{{ path('profile', {user: followed.id}) }}">see his profile</a>)</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            you don't follow anyone yet.
        {% endif %}
```

Here is the entity snippet of Following declarations

```
/**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     */, Kindly help me to get out of this.
```

and tell me if any further information is needed. Thank you in advance.
        private $follower;

```
    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    private $followed;
```

my present challenge is to be able to see all of the properties of a book published by a user e.g bookname, publisher etc that I am Following without clicking on the user that uploaded it.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for followed in followeds %}
                <li> <!-- your followed profile link etc.--> </li>
    {% if followed.books %}
    <ul>
        {% for book in followed.books %}
            <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    <ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Neither the property "books" nor one of the methods "books()", "getbooks()"/"isbooks()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\User".

Comment: can't this  your attempt be done in the controller and passed to the view

Comment: Okay. So you don't have a relationship between Books and Users. You don't have a many-to-many (or one-to-many) Doctrine relationship between them?

Comment: Then you're going to have to do a SQL join in one of your queries (yes, in the controller or in a repository) and then pass those to Twig.

Comment: I have a Many to One relationship between Books and Users

Comment: You have other problems here. The above should work if you have a getter which returns Books for Users. It's not working therefore I don't know how you're going to do it in the Controller or anywhere else.